# Interpreting ridge coefficients as a function of regularization

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, regularization, ridge-regression

Data consists of 40 observations with 4 dimensions and a response-variable.

When doing a ridge regression on my data and plotting the coefficients and coefficient errors (MSE of the ridge coefficients vs. normal linear regression coefficients) as functions of the regularization parameter 'alpha' I get the follow plots:

[image]

Can this really be the case? That the coefficient error decreases as the regularization parameter increases? Wouldn't that imply that coefficients with value ~0 is preferable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized my mistake, I calculated the ridge regression without fitting the intercept `fit_intercept = False` which obviously wont work in this comparison.

For comparison:

[image]